# Get a list of non common elements in 2 "different" vectors

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to return a list of items that is not present between vector a and b. But here is the catch

```
    struct myStruct{
        std::shared_ptr<obj> mPtr;
        int x;
    }

    vector<myStruct> listA
    vector<std::shared_ptr<obj>> listB
    vector<myStruct>result
    std::sort(listA.begin(),listA.end());
    std::sort<listB.begin(),listB.end());

    std::set_difference(listA.begin().listA.end(),listB.begin(),listB.end(),std::back_inserter(result),[](vector<myStruct>::value_type &a,vector<std::shared_ptr<obj>>::value_type  &b){return a.mPtr != b;});
```

Sadly the lambda above give me error of C2664 and C2056 even tho I "roughly" understand what it says. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Your code in the question has a lot of other errors, and it would be useful to post the full error message that you care about. However:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference: "The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that objects of types InputIt1 and InputIt2 can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to both Type1 and Type2."

So you're getting C2664 because there's no conversion from `std::shared_ptr<obj>` to `myStruct`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for info! Yeah when I read error log that is what he says, he cant convert shared_ptr to myStruct, I though if I would provide a lambda then I could do the comparison myself? In any case, I take there is no way to do this comparison then other than creating 2 matching vectors/maps/other stuff to filter it?